# Kile : pdflatex finished with exit code 1

Tags: pdftex, compiling, kile

I am writing a thesis report in Latex. I'm under Windows 7 (64bit) and using Kile 2.9.91 and MikTex 2.9.

Everything was working fine until this morning. The compilation returns this error in the picture :

[image]

Please find the log file in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D3FSYDLHox1jgMwUiLRsnC8WEkm4hm8Q).

What did I do wrong ? and how can I fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have faulty chars in your bib-file. Perhaps you copy & pasted some bib-entry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My bib entries are fully generated from Mendeley, so I have no direct control over them. How can I find the ones with faulty chars ?

Comment: Look in the log-file. The error messages contain enough context to identify the entries.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, I found the errors, some special characters that weren't readable by latin1 encoding. Maybe you should change your first comment and put it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have faulty chars in your bib-file. The error messages in the log-file give enough context to identify the entries.